# How can I stop and start individual websites in IIS using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, iis, powershell

I have multiple sites configured in IIS7 on my Windows 7 development machine to run on the same port and usually only run one at a time depending on what I'm working on.  I would like to be able to start and stop my development sites from PowerShell instead of having the IIS manager opened.  Does anyone have a good resource to point me in the right direction or a script that already accomplishes this?

Comment: There are probably WMI classes for IIS sites.

Comment: I suppose I will answer my own question by providing myself with the following link. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Just for future quick reference, the commands are:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Stop-WebSite 'Default Web Site'
Start-WebSite 'Default Web Site'
```

Comment: I'm a total PowerShell noob. Do I need to import anything prior to the code you posted? What I tried was launching PowerShell then typing the first cmd you posted and PowerShell threw an error.

Comment: After reading the exception it said that I didn't need to Import WebAdministration but next it told me that Start-Website 'SiteName' as not a recognized cmdlet.

Comment: Where did you get the module from?

Comment: It comes with PowerShell.

Comment: This is perfect. I had a website that I needed to deploy in azure dev ops, and about 30% of the time it would fail to copy dlls to the iis site folder with the reason that it was being used by another process. I added a powershell task before and after the deploy step to stop and start the site and it worked like charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Adding to Keith's answer, you can perform this remotely using Invoke-Command.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$siteName = "Default Web Site"
$serverName = "name"
$block = {Stop-WebSite $args[0]; Start-WebSite $args[0]};  
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverName
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $block -ArgumentList $siteName
```

Comment: It works but can someone explain the $args[0] part ? Thx

Comment: @ToastMan $args is the script block input argument array. [Docs for $args and other auto variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: I needed the remote command. Thanks for pointing out that there is some additional work needed to make this happen!

Answer (score 3):

To get access to system modules, Powershell needs to be run like this:

```
[path]\powershell.exe -NoExit -ImportSystemModules
```

I found the above on this [iis forum](http://forums.iis.net/t/1161621.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I found that the following to stop individual websites on a remote server to work:

```
Invoke-Command -Computername $servername -Scriptblock { 
    (Import-Module WebAdministration); 
    Stop-Website -Name "WebsiteName"; 
    Stop-Website -Name "AnotherWebsiteName"
}
```

I had some of the errors above until `Import-Module` was put in `()`

Answer (score 2):

#### Update IIS 10.0+ (2017+)

You can use the newer [`IISAdministration`](https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iisadministration-in-the-powershell-gallery) module with the [`Start-IISSite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/start-iissite?view=windowsserver2022-ps) cmdlet like this:

```
Import-Module IISAdministration
Start-IISSite -Name "Default Web Site"
```

Or by using [`Get-IISSite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/get-iissite?view=windowsserver2022-ps), you can then start / stop like this:

```
Import-Module IISAdministration
$site = Get-IISSite "Default Web Site"
$site.Start()
$site.Stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had several machines running the same website as part of an IIS web farm. I needed a script that would take a list of machines, and stop or start the website on each machine. All the machines use a shared file repository and the files are locked by the respective website when running. I have to stop all the sites to make file updates. (website not of my own design... it's part of an ERP application.)

Here's my take on this automated stop/start script:

```
#uncomment the relevant action stop or start.
$action = "start"
#$action = "stop"

#Enter the name of your website as seen in IIS.
$website = "Website Name"

#Create an array of server names (FQDN or just the AD host name)
$serverList = @(
    "server1.domain.com",
    "server2.domain.com",
    "server3.domain.com"
)

#Loop through the server name array and perform the action.
ForEach($server in $serverList) {
    #For debugging/status purposes, show the action/website/server.
    $msg = $action + "ing " + $website + " on server " + $server
    Write-Output $msg

    #Invoke a command on the remote server.
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
        $sm = Get-IISServerManager
        if ($action -eq "stop") {
            $sm.Sites[$website].Stop()
        } elseif ($action -eq "start") {
            $sm.Sites[$website].Start()
        }
        $sm.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Script assumes that

1. each remote server has remoting enabled (i.e. `Enable-PSRemoting`)
2. each remote server has the IIS Management Console is installed.
3. you may need to `Import-Module WebAdministration` on local computer running script.