# Alternate to iisreset

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have multiple sites on production server, some time one of site go down when heavy utility ended, which need iisreset, but iisreset cause all site down in resetting the iis. I want to reset the one site only, not all application pool. How i can reset my particular site of application pool.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710166/how-can-i-stop-and-start-individual-websites-in-iis-using-powershell):

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Stop-WebSite 'Your Web Site'
Start-WebSite 'Your Web Site'
```

Here is the [reference documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx) for web administration cmdlets.

Comment: you mean, i need to stop particular site from application pool and then restart? this is exactly equivalent to iisreset?

Comment: n m using IIS 6, the documentation is  for Windows PowerShell cmdlets in IIS 7. is this work in IIS6 also?

Comment: For IIS 6 you may want to use iisweb.vbs (comes with IIS itself); please see [here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/9ea4de7a-591a-48a6-84d8-0145fc594139.mspx?mfr=true) for additional details.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a change to the web.config file - a non breaking change like an extra space in between attributes save and revert.  This will cause just that site to recycle.

Comment: Ya, i did this, is this exactly equivalent to iisreset?

Comment: iisreset recycles all sites and app pools, modifying just a site web.config affects just that site.  This is quick and dirty and depends on if you have access to production systems in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

You got to have independent AppPool for each of your website. And recycle each of them anytime you need. In general putting all the websites under the same AppPool is not a good practice though, unless you have some specific goal to achieve by this.