# Website hosted on iis not accessible remotely

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012

I have a website written in asp.net, hosted on windows server 2012 VPS(IIS).
For some reason, I can't access the website on my local PC and phone. It's working fine in the vps.

Error messaged on web browser(s)

> www.example.com - Refused to connect
>   http://example.com - Not Found|HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.
>   https://www.example.com | Redirects to https - refused to connect.

I don't have any bindings as I don't know much about that.
Tried disabling windows firewall, Same problem.

Namecheap DNS records :

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you checked firewall settings?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29458715/842112

Comment: Yes. I disabled the firewall. Didn't work.