# ASP.NET MVC: How to update ASP.NET MVC Site on production

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, wix, installation, inno-setup

I need to create some patch/update for existing ASP.NET MVC Legacy application:
Update should:

1. Stop IIS site
2. Replace dll(s) and other content
3. Update MS SQL database (add new columns to several tables)
4. Start IIS site.

Need to do it on the production system and do not want to force customers to do it by hands. Also, do not know if Wix Installer should be appropriate choice (just 4 steps, and creation of Installer will take a lot).

Maybe some application exists which could help to automate such steps?

P.S: Migration of DataBase is not an option as well cause legacy system does not use EF. Application contains Inno-Setup installer which installs system from the scratch, but does not do for the update.

Comment: Rather than stopping the site, 503 Service Unavailable would be more informative. You can add whatever human-readable text you wish. See top answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4916070/2226988).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt any single application would cover your exact setup, preferences and requirements. Choose the best or most familiar tool for each step and script together yourself using powershell. Of course you could also use an installer to trigger or coordinate the steps but a simple script would usually be sufficient (and simpler at that).

To give you some more links to get started:

1) [How can I stop and start individual websites in IIS using PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710166/how-can-i-stop-and-start-individual-websites-in-iis-using-powershell)

2) [Copy-Item](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/04/19/use-powershell-to-copy-files-and-folders-to-a-new-location/) powershell command

3) For DB use Visual Studio Database project to version your DB, export to [DACPAC container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210546.aspx) and deploy using [SqlPackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx)

Also, once you have the script snippets it is trivial to include them in your automatic CI/CD tooling, for example [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/).